# List objects from sub-elements of a list

Tags: r, plyr

What I want to do is make a list, then make a list from part of the elements of that list. I can do it in 2 steps using subset and then dlply, but I'm wondering if there's a faster way with any of the XXply methods.

So I have a dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(
    biz = sample(c("telco","shipping","tech"), 50, replace = TRUE),
    region = sample(c("mideast","americas","asia"), 50, replace = TRUE),
    date = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-02-01"), length=10, by = "1 day"),5),
    revenue = sample(500:1000,50,replace=T),
    orders = sample(0:2,50,replace=T)
)
```

Ultimately, what I'm looking for here is: For each region, a list of identity values organized by business.

The messy approach is to take a subset for each region then simply turn that into a list:

```
mideast <- subset(data, region == "mideast")
americas <- subset(data, region == "americas")
asia <- subset(data, region == "asia")

mideast.list <- dlply(mideast, .(biz), identity)
americas.list <- dlply(americas, .(biz), identity)
asia.list <- dlply(asia, .(biz), identity)
```

Easy enough but it gets unwieldy with bigger datasets.

If I use *dlply* on the original data, it gives me the values I'm looking for, but again, I want to have actual list objects for each region. So:

```
list2 <- dlply(data, .(region, biz), identity)
```

But then how do I access just the regions from *list2* and create separate list objects out of them?

Comment: if you look at `attributes(list2)` you can see a `data.frame` called `split_labels`:  `attributes(list2)$split_labels`.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: So those are the splits I'm looking for, in the Region column. But how do I use those to create individual list objects for each region that are identities organized by "biz" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear I understand what you're trying to do, but maybe this is it?

```
lst <- lapply(
  split(data, data$region), 
  function(df) lapply(split(df, df$biz), identity)
)
lst[["americas"]][["shipping"]]
#         biz   region       date revenue orders
# 3  shipping americas 2010-02-03     621      2
# 23 shipping americas 2010-02-03     799      2
# 33 shipping americas 2010-02-03     920      0
# 34 shipping americas 2010-02-04     705      2
```

This matches the structure of `americas.list`, so I think this is what you're trying to do.  Also, note that you can skip the inner `lapply` if `identity` is really the function you want to apply (`split` alone does what you need).

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. Since I'm trying to make sure I understand the plyr arguments as much as possible, doing the same via plyr would be: newlist <- lapply(dlply(data, .(region)),function(df) dlply(df, .(biz), identity)) ... so it's just a matter of passing additional split arguments as the function to the original argument, right?

Comment: @MarcTulla If you want to use `dlply`, then use this: `list2 <- dlply(data, .(region), function(df) split(df, df$biz))`.  Instead of using the `identity` function, write a function that will do the `split`.  Note you can't pass additional `split` arguments because that additional argument depends on the `region` split itself.

Comment: That works! But now how do I access the sub-elements of that list? Say I want to turn these all into time-series objects so I can analyze by region. For a single-level list, I'd do: new.xts <- llply(list, function(list{xts(x=list[,"revenue"], order.by=list[,"date"])}) but since the "revenue" and "date" variables are nested within the "biz" that is in turn within "region", this doesn't work...

Comment: @MarcTulla, I think this is becoming a new question. Also, you may want to more fully explain what you are trying to do (in a new question).  I'm not convinced nested lists are the best solution for you here, but not knowing your full workflow I can't say for sure.